# ASP GridView change through pagination

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

This is my scenario.

I have a result set in an ASP GridView presented on a webpage. The GridView is displayed on a screen for viewing by a team that needs to see the information.

However, there is a lot of rows to display, so I have enabled auto paging to keep the results on each page...is there a way to automatically change through the pagination?

Thanks

Code:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView2.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;/* y
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
        GridView1.DataBind();
    } 

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to update the grid data when the user changes pages?  If so, something like this should work:

Add this to the grid:

```
onpageindexchanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged"
```

And this to the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = /* your data source */
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: yeah the idea of the page updating on changes is a good addition. I added the code to my default.aspx.vb page, but get the following message: Server Error in '/' Application.